# I'm trying to install Lindo API For my Laptop (Ubuntu 20.04) but get stuck after exporting the tar.gz file

Tags: 20.04, executable

After exporting the tar.gz file, there is one file named runlindo, which tyoe is executable (application/x-executable) yet it won't run. In addition, the readme from the developer doesnt give instructions on how to run the app. I've already tried the `./runlindo` code but it gives

```
Please give the name of the lindo or mps file: runlindo


Input any desired options (e.g., -bar) one per line.
Enter a blank line to continue.
 Option: 
LINDO API Version 14.0.5099.345 built on Mar  9 2024 04:28:08
Barrier Solver Version 0.0.000, Nonlinear Solver Version 3.17N
Platform Linux 64x86 (D)

Copyright (c) 2023 by LINDO Systems, Inc. Licensed material,
all rights reserved. Copying except as authorized in license 
agreement is prohibited.

Loaded Mosek version 10.1.13
Number of users allowed=1   
No expiration date
Lindo Staff 

Reading model parameters from runlindo.par
Warning: Could not open file for problem I/O. (error:2002)
Reading model parameters from lindo.par
Reading runlindo in MPS format (unformatted)
MPS Reader: There is an error in the input model file.
Invalid free format, trying fixed format...


Error 2003: There is an error in the input model file. 
Error line num: 0 
Line          : ''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You've Already Installed Runlindo

This application is a Mathematical Solver.  You build Mathematical Models with other  software and export them as `.lp` files or `.mps` files.  See [.lp FileType](https://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/LINDO-format.htm) and [Application Models Library](https://lindo.com/index.php/application-models-library).  The Application Solves the model, and no more.